# PHPExcel loading protected workbook

Tags: phpexcel

I have 35 protected workbook. I'm using PHPExcel to extract information from respective excel files. Unfortunately, PHPExcel failed to load the file I suspect due to protected workbook. Here's my code:

```
$inputFileType = PHPExcel_IOFactory::identify($inputFileName);
$objReader = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createReader($inputFileType);
$objReader->setReadDataOnly(true);
$objPHPExcel = $objReader->load($inputFileName);
```

Is there any workaround to enable PHPExcel to extract the information from protected workbook?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

Note that from version 1.8.0, PHPExcel **does** support reading protected Excel5 workbooks. It isn't covered in the documentation because you don't need to do anything special,  PHPExcel simply decrypts the document as it reads it

Note that this doesn't apply to documents with a user password, but "VelvetSweatshop" protected documents

http://meindertjan.nl/2012/08/22/microsoft-offic-and-its-velvetsweatshop-password-protected-files/

Comment: Mr. Baker, could you please point me to where is this specified in the docs? I can't find it and reaaaally need this. Thank you.

Comment: It isn't covered in the documentation because you don't need to do anything special.... PHPExcel simply decrypts the document as it reads it... this isn't documents with a user password, but "VelvetSweatshop" protected documents - http://meindertjan.nl/2012/08/22/microsoft-offic-and-its-velvetsweatshop-password-protected-files/

Answer (score 0):

In short, PHPExcel does not support protected sheets / workbook . See: http://phpexcel.codeplex.com/discussions/244865